# Could not find method kapt() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

I'm facing a problem for over 3 days now and I can't solve.
since I started to use Kotlin for Android,I stopped using "annotationProcessor" and started using "kapt", all things were working great with kapt until I started to build an Android Instant App, when I add "kapt" to any dependency like Glide or ButterKnife Gradle always displaying error that cound't find method kapt()

```
Could not find method kapt() for arguments [com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Here are my project Gradle files

Project gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app module gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.instantapptest.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

base module gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    application project(':app')
    feature project(':feature')


    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15.0'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'

}
```

feature module gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':base')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

instantapp gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

==========

**Solved**

by adding kotlin-android plugin to the base module

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also apply `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`?

Comment: Thanks, it's working now, I didn't notice that kotlin-android plugin wasn't applied in the base module.

Comment: Better to answer against your question and marked it accepted for better visibility of the solution/fix.

Answer (score 310):

In my case,I was missing

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. This was missing in my old project and I got the same error when migrating to AndroidX. Thanks.

Comment: This happened to me when adding Hilt. Above solution worked

Comment: `id 'kotlin-kapt'`.

Comment: Make sure it's at the top of your base module gradle file. Putting it at the bottom doesn't work.

Comment: @CoolMind It helped someone as 'Lazy' as me to write  #perfmatters

Answer (score 133):

Here is a working solution for the latest version of android studio
instead of apply plugin use `id 'kotlin-kapt'` inside plugins.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Answer (score 27):

In case anybody struggles with **Room library**:

I tried all above tips and nothing helped, unless I changed this miserable:

```
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
```

into:

```
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
```

At first, I also changed:

```
val roomVersion = "2.4.2"
```

into:

```
def roomVersion = "2.4.2"
```

AND THIS FINALLY DID THE JOB !!!

Comment: annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion") worked for me!

Comment: Great to hear that! :-D

Comment: Finally something that worked! why do we have to use Stackoverflow when following developer advice from the source? I just don't get it.

Answer (score 19):

I faced this same error when I was trying to add Room library in my android project.
As of Aug 17th, 2022, I could solve the issue adding below lines in **build.gradle(:app)**.

In the **plugins** block I added;

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
```

in the **dependencies** block, I added;

```
def room_version = "2.4.3"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Doing so, I could say goodbye to the "Could not find method kapt() for arguments".
Hopefully someone out there could save some time reading this post.

Answer (score 11):

So you also forgot to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
```

in app level gradel file. Nice.

Answer (score 5):

I faced this

> Could not find method kapt() for arguments

error, when I tried to add dependencies for `dagger` in my project.
Here is a working solution for the latest version of Android Studio.

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
   id 'kotlin-kapt'   //Add this line in the plugins block usually seen at the top of build.gradle
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Use plugin with this order,

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin:  'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved using older version of room library.
I switched from 2.6.1 to 2.6.0

Comment: Could have been a comment not an answer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Undoubtedly, people added the     ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
libarary instead of
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).