# Plugin [id: 'kotlin-kapt'] was not found in any of the following sources: Gradle Core Plugins & Plugin Repositories

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-jetpack

I tried adding Room to my Jetpack Compose project, as described here:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room?authuser=1

I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/088pe.png)

I did this:
(as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66114787/20009330)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGdRr.png)

I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVX3v.png)

Here is the github repo:
https://github.com/folsze/AudioHub

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add it on the **app build.gradle** file at the top where it will look like this:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

At the moment you have it in your **project build.gradle** file so it's in the wrong place.

Comment: Note that for Android Studio Hedgehog Patch 2 (maybe earlier, but I'm on this) this now requires version numbers for  those plugins, like: `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.9.22" apply false` (if you are using kotlin)

Answer (score 4):

The correct way is to add this line in your plugins scope in app level build.gradle

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you occour this error then or not found 'kapt' type error then
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' add this to your app build.gradle plugins field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).